# Ways to choose tickets to get a sum of $30$

Tags: combinations

There are tickets which are numbered from $0$ to $30$. In how many ways can three tickets be withdrawn so that the sum of the numbers is $30$?

Comment: It would help to clarify if there is only one ticket with each number, or if a number can appear on multiple tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of ways to distribute $30$ among three tickets equals:

$${30 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} = {32 \choose 2} = 496$$

However, this includes cases where two or more numbers are the same. How many invalid pairs of numbers are there? Simply subtract this number from $496$ to arrive at the correct answer.